# How to run query on specific time in ASP NET webpage?

Tags: asp.net, triggers

I would like to know, is it possible to run a query on specific time (for example every day at 0.00) like a trigger and how to do it.
Thanks, Oak.

Comment: Query == SQL Query?  What DB Server platform?  SQL Server?  SQL Server has an agent that can execute a "Query" according to a schedule.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scheduled+task

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You tagged this question with asp.net. So I am assuming that you need a web page to trigger the SQL  query.

Here are your options:

- If you want a asp.net page to do this all by itself, you will need to use HTML refresh, or response.redirect with a loop server side. The loop will serve as a timer (ugly code). The html refresh on the other side is highly inefficient but widely used by html chat.
- You can create a custom built assembly for your asp.net web site. Inside the assembly use the timer control
- You can create a console app, that will be run as a windows service. Then use task scheduler to run
- You can use SQL server agent and create a job that will run the query. Then schedule the job. This approach will not invoke an asp.net page.

Comment: I think the SQL server agent is the thing that im looking for. Thanks

Comment: Wow, where to start; Looping Response.Redirect serves as a "timer"? No... it serves as a never-ending loop. "HTML Refresh" is widely used by html chat? No... no, it is not. Use a Timer in an ASP.NET website? No! Don't do this - ever! "Console App" as a "Windows Service"? No!! No such thing - it's one or the other, not both. SQL Server Agent to invoke an ASP.NET page?? Why... when the intent is to run a *query*?

Comment: Wow, Where to start: Looping a response.redirect serves as a never ending loop. (Correct), Timers are never ending loops. So is SQL server Agent. That is also a never ending loop that triggers a command if the time matches.

Comment: Wow, where to start continued: How to build a chat window using HTML refresh http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/Docs/Internet/Web%20Scripting%20Secret%20Weapons/ch10.htm

Comment: Wow where to start Final: Running a windows service as a console app
http://blog.activa.be/index.php/2007/07/running-a-net-windows-service-as-console-application/

Comment: I cannot make you remove the minus points, but I can defend myself with FACT, not opinion....

Answer (score 1):

If no one is currently using your site it will go in a sleeping state(process gets killed) after 20 minutes. Even if you manage to hook into your system date you won't be able to garantee a living process to run your code.
The best way to achieve this would be to create a small console application which you can schedule on your server(with scheduled tasks).
Make sure the user executing this task has sufficient rights to do so(logon as a batch job).